# Android Database inspector showing close

Tags: android, database, sqlite, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am trying to use Database Inspector in Android Studio. always showing my application database (highlighted in the image) as "closed".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXh3a.png)